# Copying some parts of file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, grep, sed

I am to copy **"SNMP Agent is up"** and **"::=101"** and **count the number of variables present** (example here there are 5) and put them in 3 Different variables.

```
FROM  FILE.TXT
sCSISmart1  TRAP-TYPE   
    ENTERPRISE  cyclone                        
    VARIABLES  { scellNameDateTime,                      
                     scellSWComponent,                     
                     scellECode,                  
                     scellCAC,                     
                     scellEIP}                           
    DESCRIPTION                             
    "SNMP Agent is up."                       
    --#TYPE "SNMP Agent is up."                    
    --#SUMMARY "SNMP Agent is up"                    
    --#ARGUMENTS {}                           
    --#SEVERITY INFORMATIONAL                       
    --#TIMEINDEX 100                  
    --#STATE OPERATIONAL                    
    --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"                          
    --#HELPTAG 101                    
::=  101
```

What will remain constant in all other files

```
DESCRIPTION "  ";   
::= xxx(number);      
VARIABLES { variable1, variable2}
```

Any commands SED, GREP, AWK or anything else that I can use here take these out from the file.txt

**What I need is that I find DESCRIPTION and copy the text that comes after it. The same for the number I find ::= and copy text after it. For variable I find VARIABLE and find the number of variables after it.**

So assume these variables
desc is variable for DESCRIPTION
numvar is total number of VARIABLES
casenum is the number that comes after ::=

So when I print these above variables then

OUTPUT for
desc variable

> SNMP agent is up.

OUTPUT for
numvar variable

> 5

OUTPUT for
casenum variable

> 101

**EDIT**
FOR NO VARIABLES

> sCSISmart2 TRAP-TYPE
>       ENTERPRISE  cyclone
>       DESCRIPTION
>       "SNMP Agent is down."
>       --#TYPE "SNMP Agent is down."
>       --#SUMMARY "SNMP agent is down"
>       --#ARGUMENTS {}
>       --#SEVERITY INFORMATIONAL
>       --#TIMEINDEX 100
>       --#STATE OPERATIONAL
>       --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"
>       --#HELPTAG 102
>   ::=  102

FOR ONE VARIABLE

> sCSISmart6 TRAP-TYPE
>       ENTERPRISE  cyclone
>       VARIABLES {cycHostAdapterNumber}
>       DESCRIPTION
>       "The HostAdapter# %d has Failed"
>       --#TYPE "Host adapter failed"
>       --#SUMMARY "The HostAdapter# %d has Failed"
>       --#ARGUMENTS {0}
>       --#SEVERITY CRITICAL
>       --#TIMEINDEX 100
>       --#STATE OPERATIONAL
>       --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"
>       --#HELPTAG 110
>   ::=  110

Comment: I would like to know the reason why I  have been downvoted. If their is some problem with my questioning I would like to know so that it never happens again

Comment: I didn't, but... Is this something you need to do on a regular base or incidentally? It would be easy to write a small script that does the job with the file as argument, but that might be a bit overdone for a single-time usage.

Comment: @SamFlynn There is some downvoter on questions today. Do not worry. I did not downvote, but vote to close as off-topic.

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm No, I have to do the same thing for around 237 files.

Comment: @Pilot6 Sorry I dont understand "vote to close as off topic"?

Comment: To my mind this question is not about Ubuntu. But this is arguable.

Comment: @Pilot6 It's more about programming indeed, however we've always kept questions like this (just browse the `sed` /  `grep` / `perl` / `awk` / `text-processing` tags)

Comment: Let me get this straight.  You want to count number of variables between lines containing "SNMP agent is up" and "::=" . Right ? Each non empty line being a variable , right ?

Comment: I don't quite understand. As per how I read the question your asking to count the occurences of 2 strings "SNMP Agent is up" and "::=101", however there's no occurence of the second string hence I assumed you meant "::= 101" (mind the space), and in any case that would add to 4. Plus you want to count the number of occurences of two strings, how should they get store into three different variables? One for the total, one for the first string and one for the second string?

Comment: @Serg No i want to could the number of variable in the function VARIABLES. For that I have to get to find VARIABLES first in the text file.

Comment: Can we assume that `DESCRIPTION` always comes after the `VARIABLES {}` block?

Comment: @kos Yes DESCRIPTION will always come after the VARIABLES { }. However sometimes in some files the VARIABLES aren't present. So its preferable finding DESCRIPTION by not be depending on VARIABLES{ }

Comment: @SamFlynn can you show us an example how the output should look like ?

Comment: There's a little flaw in the version me and Serg posted, which might display the wrong number of variables if there are none or only one variable. Is this a possible case? And how does the format of the file change in case of none or only one variable? Perhaps the optimal thing would be that you post an example for both cases.

Comment: Added the example for both cases.

Comment: Ok, I tested them both and they both work flawless. I updated mine to also match whitespaces which where not present the last time I checked the sample, now if there are they will be stripped before being printed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly it can be done way better. However it can be done using these 3 commands:

```bsh
desc="$(< inputfile awk '/DESCRIPTION/ {getline; sub(/^\s*"/, ""); sub(/"\s*$/, ""); print}')"
numvar="$(< inputfile awk '/VARIABLES/,/DESCRIPTION/ {count++}; END {if (count>0) print count-1; else print 0}')"
casenum="$(< inputfile awk '/::=/ {sub(/^\s*::=\s*/, ""); sub(/\s*$/, ""); print}')"
```

Comment: What i need is that I find DESCRIPTION and copy the text that comes after it. The same for the number I find ::= and copy text after it. For variable I find VARIABLE and find the number of variables after it.

Comment: @SamFlynn Ok I think I've got it, let me update the answer

Comment: @SamFlynn See if the update is what you were looking for.

Comment: This kind of does it for me.Thank you! this is the most helpful community ever!

Comment: @SamFlynn Looking at the updated question it looks like you want only the first line after DESCRIPTION (stripped of the double-quotes). If that's the case the first command should be rewritten, because as of now it catches everything until `::=`

Comment: @SamFlynn I updated anyway, now it matches exactly the output you described.

Comment: @SamFlynn I also updated the third command since after the edit there are multiple spaces before the number, now you should be set.

Comment: One question about your numvar does it count more than one variable?

Comment: @SamFlynn Yes it does, as per your requirement

Comment: I have edited my example  `ONE OR MORE VARIABLES` , your `numvar` just doesn't seem to work on this.

Comment: For some reason it only prints `1`. if there are 2/3/4/5 variables.

Comment: @SamFlynn Because the command was designed with your input file in mind (i.e. one variable per line). If you change the rules obviously it's not going to work. Use this command: `numvar="$(< inputfile awk '/VARIABLES/ {FS=","; print NF}')"`. Please don't change your question ever after an acceptance, ask a new question instead. If you do any answer given until then will become useless.

Comment: if you could also add a condition to this that if no variables is there then 0 will be put into `numvar`. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SamFlynn It should be working like that already. Do you mean in case the whole VARIABLE line is not there?

Comment: It's okay I just made a work around in my code.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:

Create a file, call it whatever you like, and copy the awk script bellow into it. `chmod +x scriptname.awk` to make it executable.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {var_num=0} 
/VARIABLES/,/}/ {
    sub("{","");
    sub("}","");
    sub("VARIABLES",""); 
    if ($0~/[[:alpha:]],/||/[[:alpha:]]/)var_num+=1
    }

 /DESCRIPTION/{ 
    getline; printf "%s,",$0
    } 
/::=/ {
    printf $2","
    }
END{ printf var_num }
```

Now here's my example of running the script:

```
$ IFS=","; ARRAY=($(./three-lines.awk test-text.txt  | xargs echo ))                               
$ echo ${ARRAY[0]}; echo ${ARRAY[1]}; echo ${ARRAY[2]}                                             
SNMP Agent is up. 
101
5
```

Effectivelly, this creates an array of 3 elements, and those elements are what awk script extracts form a file. Regex [[:alpha:]] is used to consider alphabetical scrings and alphabetical strings with comas as variables, hence var_num gets incremented; if there's no lines that match that pattern, var_num is not incremented
**ORIGINAL**

Here's my awk one-liner:

`awk 'BEGIN {var_num=0} /VARIABLES/,/}/ {sub("{","");sub("}","");sub("VARIABLES",""); var_num+=1} END{ print var_num}' test-text.txt`

Basic idea: create variable `var_num`, tell awk to read everything between lines containing VARIABLES string and curly brace }. Get rid of that string, all the curly braces, and we only have strings that represent variables. Add 1 for each line to `var_num`. In the end - print the total of counted variables.

The reason for deleting VARIABLES and curly braces, is that we don't want to count lines that contain *only* VARIABLE string or the curly brace. So we need to make sure they're gone.

Another pattern that I've noticed is that each variable is coma-separated. Thus you could use an if statement , something like `if ($0~/,/) { var_num+=1 }`

Comment: See [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/636626/copying-some-parts-of-file/636634#comment908884_636634) comment (and the updated question); I understood the same at first, but the question changed dramatically (and it's way more harsh now)

Comment: @kos see my edit

Comment: this is what it says @serg                                                                                            awk: run time error: not enough arguments passed to printf(" "The HostAd,")er# %d with HostAdapter Id %s and Manager Id %s is discovered"
 FILENAME="adaptec.mib" FNR=231 NR=231
xargs: unmatched double quote; by default quotes are special to xargs unless you use the -0 option

Comment: @SamFlynn strange. Printf  statements all have arguments. I've also tested the awk script just now to show kos, here's the output : http://paste.ubuntu.com/11718718/

Comment: @SamFlynn I think the issue is with " "The HostAd" , there's an extra double quote there

Comment: Ah, Yes thats the problem. I have another task to think about now. Till now I was considering only on TRAP-TYPE in a file. If there are more than one TRAP-TYPE, then everything changes. Will probably have to break the file into multiple parts containing only one TRAP-TYPE definition and then apply these commands to find desc, numvar and casenum.

Comment: @SamFlynn no idea what you're talking about with TRAPS, but . . . . keep on rock-n-rolling, right ? :D  Mean while, I'm gonna edit my answer a little. Fixing a small bug

Comment: @Serg for some reason kos's `numvar` command isn't working. looking at your `awk one-liner` I tried doing it using the comma separated but I am having problems doing so. I am going to edit the example with the variable. Can you please update your answer to show me how its done using comma?

Comment: As soon as I get back home,  I'll edit my answer. I'm out of town so far.  I've looked through the examples. As I understand you're gonna put variables all on one line. Is that right ?

Comment: @Serg No the problem is that in some files all variables are on the same line, in some they are like one variable per line.  As far as I know, it would be best if I count the number of `commas` occurring between the curly brackets  of `VARIABLE` and add `+1` to that.  Any idea how i could do that? Thanks!

Comment: @SamFlynn I think I've done that before but rejected the idea. There's a history of edits to each answer.  You could check that. If it's not there, I'll post a version that does the count of comas +1. It's a fairly simple thing really

Comment: @Serg Found it in your 4th edit. But it doesn't seem to work, it counts `1` for 2/3/4/5 number of variables.

Comment: @SamFlynn OK, I'll work on this. Will let you know once I'm done

Comment: @SamFlynn Variables are just words, right ? so if we print everything between VARIABLES and DESCRIPTION, scrip those two strings out, strip out the curly brackets and comas, and run words count, we will get number of variables. Right ? `awk '/VARIABLES/,/DESCRIPTION/ {gsub("VARIABLES"," "); gsub("DESCRIPTION"," "); gsub("}"," "); gsub("{"," ");gsub(","," ");print}' vars-test-file.txt | wc -w` This code does exactly that. This will worked for me in multiline, sameline, and no variable cases. Counting comas is unreliable, but counting words is better. Let me know what you think of this

Comment: I know some of your files are have multiple blocks of VARIABLES, but if that's not a requirement at the moment, the code above should work ^

Comment: @Serg This works well. Thanks man! There is no problem with the multiple blocks, as I have separated and stored all  `TRAP-TYPE` blocks in a array. So for each array entry I extract casenum, desc, and numvar easily.